# How to get the cast type of a value after static_cast in gdb python script

Tags: python, c++, gdb, static-cast

I want to write a gdb python script to pasrse a class.
but I cannot get the type after c++ `static_cast`.
[original type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQQVG.png)

```
class {
...
        private:
            __iter_pointer& __begin_node() _NOEXCEPT {return __begin_node_;}
            __iter_pointer                                     __begin_node_;
...
}
```

In other place, cast a __begin_node to a __node_pointer, and then using a data member __value_ in __node_pointer.

```
 __node_pointer __cache = static_cast<__node_pointer>(__begin_node());
 __cache->__value_ = _VSTD::move(__t.remove(__t.begin())->__value_);
```

the python code is:

```
 def children(self):
        begin = self.val['__tree_']['__begin_node_']
        nodetype = begin.type
        size = self.val['__tree_']['__pair3_']['__first_']
        fmt = lambda count,value : ('[%s]' % value['first'], value['second'])
        return CxxRbTreeIterator(nodetype, begin, size, fmt)
```

hear we get a nodetype which is the type of '__begin_node',i.e. '__iter_pointer', and then we forward it to CxxRbTreeIterator.
.................

In CxxRbTreeIterator,

```
def __next__(self):
    count = self.count
    self.count = self.count + 1
    if count == self.size:
        raise StopIteration
    value_ptr = self.begin.cast(self.nodetype)
    value = value_ptr.dereference()['__value_']
    self.begin = self.get_next_node(self.begin)
    return self.fmt(count, value)
```

here, value_ptr get a __iter_pointer type, and then value want to get its' member __value_, but __value_ is a member of __node_pointer rather than __iter_pointer. So python got a error, there is no member __value_.

Comment: "gdb can only get __iter_pointer" show us error messages, not your conclusions.

Comment: _end_node()->__left_ is a __iter_pointer, how I cast it to _node_pointer in gdb python script just like the static_cast does?

Comment: Can you show your Python code? It's hard to tell what's wrong without seeing anything.

Comment: Hi n.m., I reedit this question and put code there, hope you can help.

Comment: You still aren't actually showing anyone the problem.

Comment: type A was static_cast to type B in C++, while python can only get type A, cannot get type B. so cannot access B's data member.